# What happens if a Google API access-token expires in the middle of a request?

Tags: google-api, httprequest, access-token

When you upload a file through a Google API, there is the chance of that token expiring during the time the request body is being sent.

At what point in the lifetime of an HTTP request is the token's validity checked?
Does the token have to be valid at the start of the request or when the request is fully submitted?

This is particularly important on time-consuming requests, because you don't want to waste several minutes uploading a file just to find out that your access token expired and that you'll have to send the request all over again.

Answer (score 0):

APIs are generally going to perform authorization checks as early as possible in a request lifecycle. To avoid performing work that is unnecessary and to avoid and to avoid implementation details to unauthorized parties.

Although Google does not make any guarantees for how authorization is validated, I think it is relatively safe to assume it happens at the beginning of each request.

I would recommend using official [Google APIs Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) as they automatically negotiate access tokens upon expiration.